# Receiving error for PermissionSetLicense when querying for PermissionSet as community User

Tags: apex, lightning, community

All of a sudden my code stopped working today. I query in a community controller to check if the logged in user has a certain permission set to perform certain actions.

I tried breaking my query out to investigate however within the PermissionSet query, I receive the following error:

> "FATAL_ERROR System.ExternalObjectException: INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'PermissionSetLicense' is not supported."

Query:

```
SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet LIMIT 10
```

Original Query:

```
SELECT PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.Label 
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
WHERE AssigneeId != null 
AND AssigneeId = :userId 
AND PermissionSetId IN (SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE label LIKE 'Test%')
```

This last query simply throws an internal server error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to have  been a Salesforce error.  Mine was having the issue but is working again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi This is occurred due to sales force patch update (Version 11.1) .They are rolling back this patch , Now it is working.If it isn't working please raise sales force case